# Increasing MCP3008 Precision

Tags: python, pi-3, hardware

So I am creating a device to measure voltage and current using the Pi with an MCP3008 ADC chip.  I have two questions I need help finding answers to.

**1) What is the correct math to calculate current?**

So with my setup, Pin 1 (CH0) of the MCP3008 is plugged into the device I am measuring the voltage usage of, with Pin 2 (CH1) being plugged into that device after it's gone through a 0.1 Ohm resistor (or shunt, or w/e it's called).  Now initially my thought was to calculate the current, I need to first make sure I have the ADC in the proper differential setup, and then I just take the differential value, convert it to voltage, and divide by the resistance.

Only thing is I noticed that on the API page for GPIOZero, it mentions that for the MCP3008 the `.value` can be negative in differential mode.  So should I be using `abs` in my equations? Or am I fine?

**2) Is there any way to have my program show more accurate readings?**

So I've been running the chip and using a volt meter so I have a way to see if my readings are correct or not.  My problem is that for the device I'm working with, sometimes the voltage is so low (around 0.09V or lower) that it isn't even picked up by the ADC.  However the high end of the voltage for the device has honestly blown out a chip or two already.  So here's my conundrum.  I need to figure out if there is a more accurate way to measure the voltage, while at the same time trying to figure out a way to stop my MCPs from dying.  I only have a few left to work with before I have to order in more :|

EDIT: For my setup, the voltage reference is 1.15V

Comment: Mains voltage input into a MCP3008?  What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: @joan Sorry, what I mean is that for the pins that measure voltage, Pin 1 is connected directly to the device I am measuring voltage from, whereas Pin 2 is connected to that device, but through a small resistor.  I'll edit the OP to try to make it more clearer.  Unless of course this explanation doesn't help in the slightest :|

Comment: Edit your question to include the range of (DC) voltages you wish to measure as well as the (DC) voltage you are using as the reference voltage.

Comment: @joan my VREF is 1.15.  Not sure about the voltage range to be honest.  I'm kind of new to this wiring technology business stuff.  >__<

Comment: You can only measure voltages which are between 0 and VREF.